# Cannot read the variable stored in redux store outside the map function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my component, I display a list of items (through `map` function). However, outside of the `map`, I need to display another information. However, the relevant variable gets only available when iterated inside the `map`.

This variable looks like this from Redux store:

```
{1: { id:1, title: 'title', description: 'description' ... }}
```

Below is the component. The `props.assignment[1].title` outside the map throws the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

```
const SubmissionList = (props) => {

    const assignmentId = props.match.params.assignmentId;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.loading != true)
            props.fetchSubmissions(assignmentId);
    }, [])

    if (props.loading) {
        return (<div>Loading...</div>)
    }

    if (props.error) {
        return (<div>{props.error}...</div>)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h4>Submissions</h4>
            <div className="text-muted">{props.assignment[1].title}</div>

            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        props.submissionIds.map(submissionId => {
                             const submission = props.submissions[submissionId];
                             if (submission != null)
                                 return (
                                     <>
                                         <div className="text-muted">{props.assignment[submission.assignmentId].title}</div>

                                         />
                                     </>
                                )
                        })
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    submissionIds: state.submissionReducer.submissionIds,
    submissions: state.submissionReducer.submissions,
    students: state.submissionReducer.students,        
    assignment: state.submissionReducer.assignment,
    loading: state.submissionReducer.loading,
    error: state.submissionReducer.error
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchSubmissions: (assignmentId) => dispatch(FetchSubmissionsData(assignmentId))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SubmissionList);
```

This is the function where I read the data and normalize it:

```
export function FetchSubmissionsData(assignmentId) {

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(dataOperationBegin);

        axios.get('api/Submission/GetSubmissionByAssignment', { params: { assignmentId } })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Submissions are fetched.');

                const submission = new schema.Entity('submissions');
                const student = new schema.Entity('student');                
                const assignment = new schema.Entity('assignment');

                submission.define({
                    student: student,
                    assignment: assignment
                });

                const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [submission]);
                dispatch(fetchSubmissionsSuccess(normalizedData))
            })
            .catch(error => { dataOperationFailure(error) });
    }
}
```

And, here is the relevant part of the reducer:

```
case FETCH_SUBMISSIONS_SUCCESS:
     const normalizedData = action.payload.normalizedData;
     return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            error: null,
            submissionIds: normalizedData.result,
            submissions: normalizedData.entities.submissions,    
            students: normalizedData.entities.students,
            assignment: normalizedData.entities.assignment,
     }
```

I wonder what is the problem. Am I missing something about the event flow in react-redux?

Comment: `props.assignment[1]` only exists after the data is fetched,  `props.assignment[1] && props.assignment[1].title` should solve the problem

Comment: Just a complement to what @OlivierBoissé said, you could use [lodash function get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) and it would be like this: `get(props, 'assignment[1].title', '');`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé thanks! Then, why `props.submissionIds.map` does not cause the same error?

Comment: because `props.submissionIds.map` does not throw an error when `props.submissionIds` is an empty array, it juste iterate over en empty array, there is no problem to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using syntax for arrays `props.assignment[1].title`. Here you're trying to access the second element of an array when in fact you need the `"1"` key of the map.

Try using `props.assignment["1"].title` or `props.assignment.1.title` and see if it works. The reason it works in the map function is because `submissionId` is a string not a number.